# PowerShell unable to use two -Like comparison operators together

Tags: powershell

I m learning PowerShell and one of the task I did is to filter a Csv file records.

Based on this link: https://4sysops.com/archives/create-sort-and-filter-csv-files-in-powershell/ I tried something similar to:
`Import-Csv -Path '.\sample.csv' | Select-Object EmailAddress,UniqueName,LastLoginDate | ? EmailAddress -like *gmail.com -Or ? EmailAddress -like *outlook.com | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -NoTypeInformation`

But the above gives me the error mentioned in the title.
Based on this link: https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/match/ I addressed the error by using Where-Object instead after the Select-Object line as follows:
`Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -Like "*gmail.com" -Or $_.EmailAddress -Like "*outlook.com"}`

Why does the first example give me error but not the second example?

Comment: In the first example, you are using the `-like` parameter of [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) and you can only specify one instance of a given parameter at a time.  In the second example you are using the [-like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-like-and--notlike) instead.

Comment: I think your issue was syntax. like @boxdog wrote.

Comment: how can you tell when it is using -like operator or -like parameter? @boxdog

Comment: is there any difference from using two Where-Object versus chaining multiple criteria in one Where-Object?

Comment: There isn't a `-Like` parameter (*that im aware of*). He's referring to the use of `?` which is an alias to `Where-Object`. To answer your next question, yes. You're using  *simplified* syntax vs a `-FilerScript` *scriptblock* allowing the use of multiple operators

Comment: So is it something like a scope issue? Inside the scope of Where-Object, it is ok to chain multiple criteria, but using the `?` alias of Where-Object, the scope is vague and it cant tell that I am trying to chain multiple criteria inside the Where-Object?

Comment: Yes and no, it's use is meant for more complex filtering. What you've done is essentially this: `Where-Object EmailAddress -like *gmail.com -Or Where-Object EmailAddress ...`, which is just improper syntax. Like using `Get-Process Get-Process`. You can subsitute it for a RegEx filter tho: `? EmailAddress -match "outllook|gmail"`, just making use of  `-Match` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Both your commands use the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet; `?` is simply a built-in alias for it.
- However, your commands use *different syntax forms*: your first command uses the simpler and more concise, but feature-limited individual argument-based *simplified syntax*, whereas your second one uses the verbose, but fully featured script-block syntax - see next section.
- Because you need to combine *multiple* `-like` operations, you *must* use script-block syntax - simplified syntax limits you to a *single* operation.

---

**Regular, *script block*-based syntax**:

Example:

```bash
# You're free to add additional expressions inside { ... }
Where-Object { $_.EmailAddress -like '*gmail.com' }
```

uses a *single argument* that is a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), inside of which the condition to test is formulated based on the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) that represents the input object at hand.

This syntax:

- Places ***no* constraints on the complexity of the expression** - the whole PowerShell language is at your disposal inside a script block.
- However, it is somewhat **verbose**.

---

**Simplified, *multi-argument* syntax:**

Example:

```bash
# Equivalent of the above.
# Note the absence of { ... }, $_, and "..." 
Where-Object EmailAddress -like *gmail.com
```

[*Simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) is an alternative syntax that may be used with `Where-Object` as well as [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), which:

- as the name implies, is **simpler and less verbose.**
- but is **limited to a *single* conditional / operation based on a *single property***, or, in the case of *method* calls with `ForEach-Object`, the input object itself.

With simplified syntax **the parts that make up a conditional / method call are passed as *separate arguments***, which therefore bind to distinct parameters that are specifically designed to work with this syntax:

- Because separate arguments are used, there is no `{ ... }` enclosure (no script block is used).
- `$_` need *not* be referenced, because its use is *implied*; e.g. `EmailAddress` is the equivalent of `$_.EmailAddress` in the script block-syntax.

  - A notable limitation as of PowerShell 7.2.x is that with `Where-Object` you cannot operate on the input object *itself* - you *must* specify a property. [GitHub issue #8357](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8357) discusses overcoming this limitation in the future, but there hasn't been any activity in a long time.
- As usual in [*argument-mode* parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), quoting around string values is optional, assuming they don't contain metacharacters such as spaces; e.g., `*.gmail.com` - without `"..."` or `'...'` - works with simplified syntax, whereas the *expression-mode* parsing inside the equivalent script block *requires* quoting, e.g. `'*gmail.com'`